# N-up (Multiple page in a sheet) layout supports in Postscript

Tags: printing, postscript, redmon

I would like to develop an application which is similar to **FinePrint**. It provides sophisticated features for the user to configure the printing setting and able to view before confirm printing.

The solution I can think of is to use **Redmon** to redirect postscript to my application and the user will be able to configure the printing setting such as n-up (Multiple page in a sheet) and preview before printing. My question is, if it possible to edit the postscript layout to support multiple page in a sheet?

Any other suggestions are welcome. If someone could explain how **FinePrint** works will be great.

Comment: start by exploring the existing utilites such as psselect and psnup. Note they will only work if your input is structured nicely, but if they dont work you have a steep hill to climb..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postscript is a language, where a document begins with page definition like "letter", which defines defines a setpagedevice and initgraphics... which initializes a new page and ends with a "showpage" which sends the raster image to the printer. To produce an n-up page, the beginning and ending commands need to be redefined to not initialize a new page and not output the page, but instead define a series of commands which will scale and position the individual pages into a super page.

If all of the pages come from the same source, it isn't too hard, but if the ages come from a variety of sources and goes to a variety of output devices it can get difficult quickly. If you want to mix pages from multiple sources on the same page can be extremely difficult.

A term you can search on google is "imposition".

Comment: All pages will come from the same source, just that I would like to achieve what Fineprint does which is able to change the n-up of a page and preview on the screen. My initial thought is to edit the doc layout (in ps). From your description, there's no easy way to change the doc layout (in ps)? I'm not sure if you have tried FinePrint. You can try the trial version. Thanks

Comment: For the preview, you'd probably use ghostscript. There is typically no layout in postscript, but instead a stream of data printing to individual pages. By trapping the start and end of the pages, the traps can insert a layout. Like a `/save mysave def` will save the current page contect, then a `.25 .25 scale` will reduce the page to 1/4 size. A 306 396 translate will move the starting point of a page to the middle. and `mysave restore` would restore the original page context. with these commands, a 1/4 size page could be placed in the lower right corner.

Comment: Postscript is a full language. Easy if you know the language, not so easy if you don't. Postscript has no formal standard for formatting pages, so page construction varies widely by application. Acrobat is more or less a standard for formatting pages, where streams of pages are composed using a similar set of definitions.

Comment: thanks for the useful information. I find that we cannot merely search the keyword `showpage` in a ps document as postscript is a language, the `showpage` may be located in a procedure. An interpreter is needed to locate it. After doing some studies on PS, I found an easier way to do it by using DSC. If the PS document is DSC conformed then we can just search the keyword `%%BeginPageSetup` to do the scaling and translation.